# Debugger hotfix for OSX Sierra and iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, macos, delphi, hotfix

Does anyone know where to get the hotfix for Mac OSX to run iOS Simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this blog article on Embarcadero's community site:

[Debugger Hotfix for macOS Sierra and the iOS Simulator](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/debugger-hotfix-for-macos-sierra-and-the-ios-simulator)

Comment: Not authorized.
Is there another method?

Comment: @Humberto do you have a valid Delphi/C++Builder/RADStudio license? Only registered users can download the hotfix, it says so right on the download page.